# How to capture key events

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-6.9, key-events

All of the examples for key listeners I have been able to find deal with components other than the main panel such as a text box or Menu.
I know how to use setMnemonic to program Menu hotkeys but this method does not seem to be available and the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/post1.0/ui/keylistener.html) to the oracle keylistener tutorial is broken.
When I do a Right Click > Events > Key > KeyPressed on the main form I get the following but none of keys cause `mainPanelKeyPressed.`
What is the correct way to use the key events to trigger an action independent of the focus?

```
mainPanel.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        mainPanelKeyPressed(evt);
    }
});

private void mainPanelKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    // Added to help find the ID of each 'arrow' key
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "mainPanelKeyPressed"); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the correct way to use the key events to trigger an action independent of the focus?

See: [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Or use a JMenuBar with menus and menu items.

Answer (score 0):

the focus is important.  you may need to click around and experiment, and use component.requestFocusInWindow() to help.